# Confusion with generics on static members of a class

Tags: java, generics

The following code is very confusing to me.

```
public class Test<T> {
  public static <T> Test<T> ok(T result) {
  ..
```

I understand the generics in class name. I could understand if "ok" method would be like this

```
public static Test<T> ok(T result) {
```

or this

```
public static T ok(T result) {
```

But why there is the extra < T > before the Test < T > return type I don't understand.

Comment: So does it return Test<T> or <T> It has "two" return types.. If it returns Test<T> why it has extra <T> before it. If it returns just T why it isn't just T without <> and without Test<T>

Comment: It´s there because compiler now know it has a generic type. and other Ts are just for filling it for normal form.

Comment: The crucial thing is that the `<T>` in front of `ok` is a _different_ T than the one in the class declaration (`class Test<T>`). You have two entirely different type parameters, though both have the same name. The one from the class declaration is only available in instance methods, and the one on `ok` is only available there. (`T result` uses the one declared for `ok`, not `Test<T>`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example is in fact equivalent to

```
public class Test<T> {
  public static <U> Test<U> ok(U result) {
  ..
```

The other `<T>` refers to a different generic type which applies only to the method. To avoid confusion, it's better to use different names for different things.

Comment: if it returns U why the method isnt just public static <U> ok(U result); or public static U ok(U result); (i guess first option makes more sense because the brackets probably highlights it is related to U as parameter of ok method, but anyway why there is also the Test<U> then if it returns U?

Comment: The first `<U>` introduces a new generic type variable, unrelated to `<T>`. From the perspective of compiler, you then have two and can use either `<T>` or `<U>` in the method. If you want to have just one, omit the extra `<U>` and use `<T>` from the class level.

Comment: Aha i See now. The first <U> introduces new generic variable as you say and the second is the return type, ok thank you.

Comment: @jurez Maybe you made a mistake here: In the static method you cannot use the generic from the **instance**, as there is no instance present.

Comment: @Vlasec Generics work at the type level, they are just "templates for classes" and not types themselves. So I don't think this is the issue here, but if you can confirm I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @jurez Generics aren't *templates like in C++*, they differ a lot. Most importantly the code isn't compiled separately for every type used. The generic parameter of a class is there to give static type safety in previously unsafe territory. The bytecode however is agnostic to generic type parameters.

Comment: @Vlasec Exactly, that's why I used quotes :-) But types (classes) in Java are static, so any generics only applies to classes, not instances. In fact, type erasure a limitation in my opinion.

Comment: @jurez Well, maybe I wasn't clear enough and you clearly didn't get what i wanted to say. The *concrete* type provided to the generic parameter is what is tied to the instance. Where you were wrong is, you told OP that he could use `T` in the static method which is wrong, as it is not visible there in a static method.

Comment: @Vlasec Thanks for clarification, you are correct. You cannot use type parameter declared on class level on static methods, you can only use it on instance methods. So `static Test<T> test(T ok)` will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

It is a *static method*, so it is unaffected by the generic type parameter of an *instance*.

If you want the `ok` method to be bound by the generic parameter , you will have to make something like `TestFactory<T>` class as a factory that only makes tests of `T` type, like that:

```
public class TestFactory<T> {
    public Test<T> ok(T result) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So in this case a `TestFactory<String>` only allows `String` results, anything else is a compiler error.

If you prefer the static method, you should do what @jurez posted to avoid confusion: The thing is, its type parameter of this static method only depends on type of given input parameter.

Comment: No problem, I updated it a bit, too. Originally I also wanted to point out what @jurez wrote, but he was faster and I don't like "stealing" :)